Manually editing PHP session file not working
For fun I have made a custom 2FA authenticator for my home website. To indicate that the user is verified and logged in a PHP session variable is set.
I am using Node.js for the backend for the authenticator, which would then use exec() to manually echo to the end of the session file, as the webserver user:
echo "loggedin|b:1;" >> PHP_SESSION
The webpage would then be reloaded, which would look for the $_SESSION['loggedin'] session variable, and if it was there allow access, if not redirect to the login page.
Now, when watching the session file on the server I can see the file get updated, but when the page reloads the session seems to get destroyed and dissapears until the new session_start(); is called. If I simulate authentication with PHP it works (and the file string appears identical).
My question is: does PHP have any sort of check to check the validity of the session file to make sure it hasnt been modified by other sources?
I have had a google around PHP.net but havent found anything that seems to answer it.
Note: I have changed tack and using the Node and MariaDB for authentication since the DB is already doing most of the legwork.
I ave read a few forum posts, but none seem to be about this issue. I have had a read of php.net sessions manual.text doesnt addresses remote clients editing the file

Why would you manually edit session files?

Honest reason? I don't know what I am doing, but thought it might be less convoluted, simpler, which it turned out not to be. Using the existing DB worked fine. I am just curious about different ways to do things and why this didn't work.

Well, what are you trying to achieve here? There are probably "better" ways to do it

Oh definitely, if this was a production server I would use an existing product. But in this case it is a 'toy' server and it is a 'see if I can do it'. The authenticator app is now functional. It uses node.js as the backend websocket server, through an apache reverse proxy. When an approval request is sent, a push message is sent to the registered device, who then either approves the login by entering the challenge number, or denies it. If the challenge is correct then the authentication database is updated, a reload is sent to the page requesting authentication which picks up the change in DB

Try to make sure that string is not echoed with double quotes in the file.
Also you have to specify the name of the PHP session file like sess_v6ltkaxqxiph3dfgktr1om9xyx

Do you mean that the quotes don't appear in the session file literally? They weren't in there. The string appeared identical to it being set using PHP. The correct session file was being used. There was only one session at the time also. I got the session id from the browser, set up a watch, which showed it was non existent, then saw it appear as I logged in, and then saw the value get shoehorned in, then saw the session dissappear. I made sure to remove all session_destroy() from the pages to rule those out

You are using >> to append loggedin|b:1;  Can you make sure session doesn't already contain entry with name loggedin|b:0; or something. Because if PHP finds duplicate key it destroys session. You can try using > (write) operator instead

That might have been it. I was appending as I already had session variables. Although my PHP never sets that variable to 0, it is either not there or set to 1. If logged in exist and is true it bypasses the auth request and redirect to the welcome page.

I might give this a test tonight, in a more controlled fashion, to see what happens

I ran some tests tonight. After creating a copy of the session file, then opening it with nano, making no changes but writing it back to file, I compared them with diff. It seemed there was a newline added which PHP didnt like. I was unable to get the exact parameter combination of runuser to work again, so not sure if this was my esact issue.
